# Integration test without mocking the connection to the other application

Tags: spring, integration-testing

I have two applications. I did integration unit tests for one of these applications, but the services that call the other application are mocked up (instead of injecting the real service, I inject another one which is mocked up).

Is there a possible way to make a real connection to the other application without having to mock it up.

A simple example would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is rather the good practice to mock things up. You need to test your service on your other application but not by testing via the first app.

Answer (score 0):

just inject the real services and do your integration test. The issue is to make sure that everything that everything that needs to be injection can be injected. Lets call your services foo and bar where foo depends on bar. if bar depends on something in the application server then starting it up during a unit might be a problem, since you are not running the app in the application server.

Integration testing is important and valuable, but it requires some careful thought to setup. The way that I have managed to setup integration testing in my application is to use spring profiles to seperate the combinations of configuration. For example I have profiles called.

- production
- development
- container
- standalone

So that way you can have a test that is launched with the proper profile that setups all the correct beans to be injected like so.

```
@ActiveProfile(profiles={"deveolpment","standalone"})
@RunWith ... etc other spring annotations to configure a test 
public class SomeJunitTest {
}
```

Using profiles makes it very easy to have fine grained control over which set of beans are configured for each test.

Also for integartion testing I have found TestNG to be much easier to use that JUnit because it has features that make writing integration tests easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how should I configure everything? I mean, I don't run the tests inside the application server. In the Testing chapter ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html ) from the spring documentation it is recommend this. How should I proceed then?